# Transfering at São Paulo airport while traveling from Pakistan to Chile

Tags: transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, brazil, gru, sao-paulo

My route is Pakistan-Istanbul-São Paulo with Turkish Airlines, then a transfer to LATAM Airlines to my final destination in Chile.

a) Do I need a transit visa?

b) Will they issue me all my boarding passes in Pakistan including LATAM Airlines?

c) Will there be any counter for LATAM Airlines in São Paulo airport transit area? Because I will not be allowed to go outside of the transit area.

d) I am arriving at Terminal 3 in São Paulo, and my next flight is from terminal 2. Will there be any way for me to go to to terminal 2 airside? Because I don't have a Brazilian visa.

Comment: Is this all on one ticket (one PNR)? What’s your citizenship? You can check visa requirements for your itinerary here [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/)

Comment: I am a Pakistani citizen, yes I have booked in one ticket number

Comment: Terminals 2 and 3 in Sao Paolo are [directly connected by a footpath](https://www.veloso.com/getting-there/airports/brazil/sao-paulo-guarulhos/). See GRU terminal transfer information [here](https://www.gru.com.br/en/passenger/to-from-gru-airport/transfer). See TWOV rules for Brazil [here](https://www.gov.br/mre/pt-br/consulado-londres/visa-section/types-of-visa/visitor-visa-vivis/visitor-visa-vivis-tourism-and-transit)